# Is save data from previous Dragon Age games used in Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Does Dragon Age Inquisition make use of save data from previous games in the series?  If so, what benefits does this provide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set up your game world for Dragon Age Inquisition using the [Dragon Age Keep website](https://dragonagekeep.com/en_US/). There you can select your actions in the past two games and import those as a game world state into DA:I.

I'm not far enough into the game to actually say anything about the consequences of setting up those past decisions, but I would imagine that they are integrated into the story in Dragon Age Inquisition.

As far as I know there is no way to import savegames directly, you have to use the Keep to set up your game world.

Comment: I wasn't even aware the 'Keep' site existed.  That was an interesting experience putting the tapestry together.  Thanks for sharing that information!

Comment: So far I have discovered that several of the options you choose regarding Dragon Age 2 outcomes will affect Varric's stories, if you ask him about Hawke.

Comment: The Keep does have the ability to import characters from previous games, however when Main Characters showed up in Inquisition, the game asked me to create their portrait anyway, despite having imported the saves into The Keep.