# What is the impact of our previous story in Dragon Age: Inquisition

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition, dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

I would like to know what is the impact of our story from Dragon Age: Origin or other previous story to Dragon Age: Inquisition.

I'm not asking for a list of each impact. I would like to know if the impact in just the world state or if it is more than that. Will I meet my previous character for instance?

Comment: Dragon age has a bunch of alternate outcomes.. this might be a little to broad for the arqade

Comment: I will edit my question then

Comment: @Timelord64 - It has multiple outcomes, [but only one is canon](http://kotaku.com/5850575/its-canon-alistair-became-king-in-dragon-age-origins)

Answer (score 1):

Minor spoiler for interactions with Morrigan, you have three different outcomes

1. Warden died- Lilianna is sad and so is Morrigan
2. Warden x Morrigan- Morrigan has a child, leads to missing child quest
3. Alastair x Morrigan- same as number 2 but does not know

may be more to it never really finished game

Answer (score 0):

It is just in the world state. I won't go into the actual choices, because that's a different question and has been answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192071/is-save-data-from-previous-dragon-age-games-used-in-inquisition).

With a little of the beginning plot, you can see where the previous games make their mark on Inquisition. While it being minor spoilers, read carefully.

> With the assistance of Hawke (the protagonist of Dragon Age II), the Inquisitor investigates the disappearance of the Grey Wardens, discovering that they were being manipulated by Corypheus into raising a demon army. Hawke and the Inquisitor are assisted by a Grey Warden character from the previous games in the series, who may be either Alistair, Loghain, or Stroud, depending on choices made in previous games.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a lot of dialog that mention previous events in passing or for example who the current Fereldan royalty are not a lot of impact on what you yourself do. Still follows the same main structure.